# How can I check, if a table has certain entries and add one, if it doesn't?

Tags: mysql, sql, python-3.x

I'm trying to check if a sql table has certain entries and if not to write them into the table. When running the code for the first time, it works as intended. It checks if there are topics written in the column. If there are none, it writes the given topic in the table. But when the method is called for a second time with a new topic, it creates several entries of the new and old topics. Here is the code i've written:

```
def check_topic(topic=None):
    topic = [topic]
    query_1 = "SELECT topic FROM topics"
    db_connection = db_connect()
    cursor = db_connection.cursor(prepared=True)
    cursor.execute(query_1)
    rows = cursor.fetchall()
    if not rows:
        query_2 = "INSERT INTO topics (topic) VALUES (%s)"
        cursor.execute(query_2, topic)
        db_connection.commit()
    else:
        for x in rows:
            for y in x:
                if topic == y:
                    pass
                else:
                    query_2 = "INSERT INTO topics (topic) VALUES (%s) "
                    cursor.execute(query_2, topic)
                    db_connection.commit()
                    break
    db_disconnect(db_connection, cursor)
```

Thanks for your hints!

Edit: I just noticed that it follows the 2^n principle. So executing the code when there are 2 entries in the table results in 4 entries after execution. 4 result in 8, 8 in 16, etc.

Comment: What's the database?

Comment: mysql hosted on phpmyadmin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should replace the first two SQL queries with a single one:

```
INSERT INTO topics (topic)
    VALUES (%s)
    ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE topic = VALUES(topic);
```

You are then doing a loop that inserts the topics a few more times.  That loop seems unnecessary.

For this to work, you need a unique constraint on `topics(topic)`:

```
alter table topic add constraint unq_topics_topic unique (topic);
```

Comment: I just tired that. It updates the topic, bit still creates severeal entries. The first run with a single topic and a single call of the method resulted in a single entriy, which was expected. The sencond run with the known topic and a new unkown topic as well as two calls of the function for the two topics resulted in four new entries in the database.

Comment: @Nordmann1861 . . . Did you remove the loop and the second `INSERT`?

Comment: Yes, I corrected the query and removed everything after the .execute, except for the .commit and the disconnect

Comment: @Nordmann1861 . . . You need a unique constraint or unique index on `topics(topic)`.  I added that to the answer.

Comment: I´ve corrected everything the way you described. Now, when executing the code, I get the following message: ```Caught exception in on_subscribe: 1061 (42000): Duplicate key name 'unq_topics_topic'``` But the code semms to work as intended.

Answer (score 0):

And if you're using a database (or a version of MySQL) that doesn't support that special syntax, you can do this using SQL ***transactions:***

(1) `BEGIN TRANSACTION`
(2) Query to see if the records exist.
(3) If not, insert the new data.
(4) `COMMIT`

An SQL transaction is *atomic:*  "either everything happens, or nothing does."  This eliminates the so-called "race condition" which could otherwise occur between steps (2) and (3) above, where two parallel processes both simultaneously decide that the rows aren't there and both simultaneously try to insert them.

https://www.w3resource.com/sql/controlling-transactions.php